# Are meta tags for pages needing user authentication helpful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, meta-tags, meta

I have built my first rails app and am in the process of some SEO optimization. It is social networking app, so it has static pages and dynamic pages. Obviously the dynamic pages need user authentication - User Profile, Friend Search, Account Setting, Messages etc. So you need an account to access these pages? Does that mean from an SEO standpoint these pages are useless?

I have a different title for each of these pages setup. But in terms of meta tags and keywords, there is really no point in having different meta tags for each of these dynamic pages is there? Since these pages require authentication.

Would I be okay if I just include meta tags in the `application.html.erb` and call it a day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any page which requires user access can not be accessed. If the non-authenticated user can not see it, how could a crawler? Spoofing to make the website think you are a crawler is fairly easy, so that would be a huge securitybreach.

There are headers which you can send to the browser, telling it that auth is required, some bots can read those.

Also, if you include google analytics, they get some information via your authenticated user :)

Comment: Okay, so the point is that I should solely focus on static pages or pages that do not require authentication, right?

Comment: It depends, do you need it? Search engines are getting better and better and trying to give the user the best result. So not the best SEO optimized page, but the best result. If you have a website which is mainly accessable after auth, SEO shouldn't be very high on your list of to-do's. 
The few pages you have can be optimized, but dont overdo it. 
Also, since your website is one with allot users, try using them to gain populairity with share-widgets and such.